# Managing output of a Vectorized function in R

Tags: r, function, output, vectorization

I have a `Vectorize`d function called `vec` (below). My goal is to be able to get a subsetable list as the output from this function. That is, when I run the function, I will be able to save the function call as an object (e.g., `I`) and then subset the desired output by using `$` from `I`, in this case like this (First run function `vec` below):

`I = vec(L = .3, U = .6, level = seq(.5, .95, .1)) ; I$alpha  ; I$beta`

Is this possible given the use of `Vectorize`? (highly appreciate your expertise)

**Here is the R function:**

```
vec = Vectorize(function(L, U, level = .95){

p1 = (1 - level)/2
p2 = 1 - p1
f.beta <- function(alpha, beta, x, lower = 0, upper = 1){
 p <- pbeta((x-lower)/(upper-lower), alpha, beta)
 log(p/(1-p)) }

delta <- function(fit, actual) sum((fit-actual)^2)

objective <- function(theta, x, prob, ...) {
ab <- exp(theta)
fit <- f.beta(ab[1], ab[2], x, ...)
return (delta(fit, prob)) }

x.p <- (function(p) log(p/(1-p)))(c(p1, p2))

sol <- nlm(objective, log(c(1e1, 1e1)), x = c(L, U), prob = x.p, lower = 0, upper = 1, typsize = c(1, 1), fscale = 1e-12, gradtol = 1e-12)

parm <- as.numeric(exp(sol$estimate))

list(alpha = parm[[1]], beta = parm[[2]])

}, c("L", "U", "level"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is it the `level` you want to loop i.e. `lapply( seq(.5, .95, .1), vec, L = .3, U = .6)`

Comment: If I look at the code, only `level` is having length greater than 1

Comment: Are those of the same length or different when the length is greater than 1.  Perhaps you need something like `expand.grid(L, U, level)`

Comment: So, in that case you may need to get all the combinations if I am right using `expand.grid` ?

Comment: Based on the function, you are already getting an output, but only thing is that it is in a `list` so, `sapply(I, '[[', 'alpha')#
[1]  2.371449  3.562465  5.278213  7.939884 12.918233` and similarly for 'beta' i.e `sapply(I, '[[', 'beta')#
[1]  2.863406  4.336959  6.461091  9.757192 15.922938`  I guess that is what you asked, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is already vectorized, but the output is in a `list`.  So, we loop through the `list` elements to extract the 'alpha' and 'beta' components

```
sapply(I, '[[', 'alpha')
#[1]  2.371449  3.562465  5.278213  7.939884 12.918233
sapply(I, '[[', 'beta')
#[1]  2.863406  4.336959  6.461091  9.757192 15.922938
```

Note that the output can simplified to a matrix with two rows

```
simplify2array(I)
```

Or a two column `matrix`

```
do.call(rbind, I)
```

Comment: @morouzian THe function itself is giving an output.  If you check the arguments, you gave `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`.  So, it is keeping the `list` structure

Comment: @morouzian Because the output is already in a `list`.  One problem with `Vectorize` is that it is difficult to wrap it inside a function because of the way it outputs

Comment: @morouzian If there are only 'alpha' and 'beta' values, then just `unlist` and extract it i.e. `unlist(I)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` Or if you want two column output `do.call(rbind, I)` or `simplify2array(I)`